# Запуск консольного приложение на С# из бат-файла

Tags: c#, bat, cmd

Написал небольшую консольную утилиту rcopy на С# для копирования файлов из одной папки в другую.

Входные параметры: `[Папка-источник] [Папка-получатель]`. Пример: `rcopy C:\src C:\dst`

Если ее использовать из командной строки, вручную вводя параметры, - все работает отлично.

Теперь решил написать батник вида:

```
@echo off
rcopy C:\src C:\dst
pause
```

Батник работать отказывается. Получаю исключение вида:

> `System.IO.DirectoryNoFoundException: Не удалось найти часть пути.`

Полагаю, что батник не обладает правами администратора.
Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы батник заработал?

Операционная система: Windows 7. Использую Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Неплохо было бы увидеть код `rcopy.`

Comment: Вообще то каталог копируется через xcopy в пакетных файлах.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать вместо rcopy -- полный путь к каталогу\rcopy.

Answer (score 1):

Если пути содержат пробелы, их обязательно в кавычки нужно брать. Мне кажется в этом ошибка, а вообще хорошо бы исходный код увидеть или сам погляди в отладке что происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Текущий исходный код утилиты: http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?3i4kehalrw2x

Разобрался в чем проблема. Дело в том, что в пути к каждой из папок имеются буквы из кириллицы. Поэтому сам батник нужно было сохранять в кодировке DOS-866.